# Context aware auto-complete

Tags: c, algorithm, design-patterns, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete algorithm for a programming language. I want it to be context aware, meaning that suggestions must appear relative to the statement the user is currently typing.

What is the best way to go around this? What algorithms should I be looking into?

Comment: First of all, you will need to write a quite smart parser for the language.

Comment: You need to implement parser of the language. Or its whole interpreter.

Comment: Take a look at existing solutions. There are plenty open source tools that support different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a state machine that recognizes the grammar of your language. Additionally, the state transitions should be weighted according to their probability.

If the state of your engine is at `public static`, the weight of the state transition `class` could be higher than that of `abstract`. This would be necessary to display a practical number of options as suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You do not actually need to parse the language to do this.

Assuming you have a list of valid symbols you need only choose the most likely completions when the user presses the autocomplete key (say, TAB, eg). You can weight the symbols by their frequency in the code. You can also weight by symbol type, giving more weight to variable names than reserved words. For example, if the user types "th[TAB]" and they have a variable named "themes" which appears 50 times, that might be the top completion, with the reserved word "then" perhaps being 2nd.

To generate the frequency weighting you need to count the number of times each symbol appears in the code. This can be done using a standard string search algorithm.

If you do have a parser, you can do more fancy things. For example, if you determine all the methods of a class and the user enters the symbol for an instance of a class followed by a period, you can automatically display a list of the methods, because those are the only valid possibilities.

BTW: To build the symbol list will depend on the language. For example, if it is Java, you can use the built-in introspection methods to identify all the defined symbols.